# Перенос программы на Spring Boot версии 3.2.3 на 2.5.6

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Изучаю Spring Boot и столкнулся с конфигом по обучению, но его нет в версии 3. Хочу перейти на более позднюю версию. Пробовал изменить pom файлы, выдает ошибку: Could not find artifact com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:pom:unknown in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Comment: Мало что понятно. В заголовке объявлен переход на более старую версию, а в вопросе вы пишете, что хотите перейти на более позднюю. Уточните, что вы хотите сделать, и помимо ошибки приведите хотя бы настроечные файлы из вашего проекта.